# Deleting columns from a data frame based on presence/absence of certain values

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, multiple-columns

I would like to subset a data frame by removing columns that meet or do not meet a certain condition. For example, given the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(w = c('a', 'b', 'c'), 
                 x = c(1, 0, 0), 
                 y = c(0, 1, 0), 
                 z = c(0, 0, 1))
```

Which gives:

```
  w x y z
  a 1 0 0
  b 0 1 0
  c 0 0 1
```

I would like to remove columns that contain a 0 after subsetting the rows. For example:

```
df %>% filter(., w == 'a')
```

Produces:

```
w x y z
a 1 0 0
```

Which I would like to then reduce to:

```
x
1
```

I am looking to do this using `dplyr`, thus the next step should be piped after the `filter` command. I have tried using `summarise` in conjunction with apply, but that has not worked.

Comment: Clunky but in base you can use: `lapply(df$w,function(x){df[which(df$w == x),which(df[which(df$w == x),] != 0)]})` That will give you a list for each of the values in `df$w`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `select_if()`:

```
df %>% filter(w == 'a') %>% select_if(function(col) is.numeric(col) && all(col != 0))

#  x
#1 1
```